# Clearing text for a Choose Files button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that uploads multiple images:

```
<form action="uploadImages.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
    <input type="file" id="imageFiles" name="Images[]"  multiple="multiple" help_token="upload_token" size=20 />  
    <input type="button"  id="submitImages" help_token="upload_token" value="Upload" />
    <img id="loadGif" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="load gif" />
 </form>
```

[image]

Above I've just selected 5 files and when I select Upload they'll be uploaded. If I select another set of files after that, the "5 files" is still displayed until I've actually selected the new set of files. I'd like this text to go away as soon as I've selected "Choose Files" but I don't seem to be able to get a hold of that text. It seems to be controlled completely by the browser. Is there a way I can clear it as soon as the "Choose Files" button (input#imageFiles) is selected?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you want to clear the text? After the upload has been initiated, or after successful completion of upload (if so, how do you determine successful upload)? Can you please show your relevant JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: As soon as the upload is initiated, i.e., as soon as "Choose Files" is selected. I have jQuery that clears any last errors when "Choose Files" is selected:  $('input#imageFiles').click( function(e) {
    $('#galleryStatus2').empty();}  But I know where that text is, in that case,  because I made the div for it.  I don't know where the "5 files" text is.

Comment: The `5 files` represents the `FileList` object, containing the selected files. This can be "cleared" after "Upload" is clicked, files submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

html

```
<!-- add `value` attribute to `file` input -->
<input type="file" id="imageFiles" name="Images[]"  multiple="multiple" help_token="upload_token" size="20" value="" />
 <!-- adjust `button` type to `submit` -->
<input type="submit"  id="submitImages" help_token="upload_token" value="Upload" />
```

js

```
$("#UploadForm").on("change submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.target.files) {
    console.log(e.target.files) // files selected
  } 
  else {
    var data = {};
    var files = $(e.target).find("#imageFiles")[0].files;
    [].slice.call(files).forEach(function(val, i) {
        data[val.name] = val // files object
    });
    var request = $.ajax({
        url:$(e.target).attr("action"),
        data:{json:JSON.stringify(data)}, // files as `json`
        type: $(e.target).attr("method"),
        dataType:"json",
        context:$(e.target).find("#imageFiles")
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // files
        $(this).val("").change(); // clear `value`
     }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
           console.log(textStatus, error);
           $(this).val("").change();
     })
   }
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0dq11b8o/